# Debian6 FailoverIP Config

Tags: networking, debian

Hi i ordered a new ip adresse for my server and now i have a problem with the config.
Main IP is 5.xx.xx.xx, the new ip which i have ordered is 46.xx.xx.xx.
So anyone can tell me where i did a mistake?

OS: Debian6
Host:OVH

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0 iface eth0 inet static
        address 5.xx.xx.xx
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 5.xx.xx.0
        broadcast 5.xx.xx.255  
        gateway 5.xx.xx.254

post-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0:0 5.xx.xx.xx netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast5.xx.xx.255   
post-down /sbin/ifconfig eth0 down 
post-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0:1 46.xx.xx.xx netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast
46.xx.xx.255 
post-down /sbin/ifconfig eth0:0 down


auto eth0:0 iface eth0:0 inet static
        adress 46.xx.xx.xx
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 46.xx.xx.255
```

Comment: You bought from OVH? Anyway, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You are first adding 5.xx.xx.xx on eth0, then you are adding 5.xx.xx.xx again on eth0:0 and 46.xx.xx.xx on eth0:1 with your `post-up` commands, then you try to add 46.xx.xx.xx again on eth0:0 with the block at the end.

Get rid of the `post-up` and `post-down` lines, then everything should be fine.

Comment: i removed the 4 lines but after typing: ifup -a
Don't seem to have all the variables for eth0:0/inet.

Comment: Try `/etc/init.d/networking restart`. If it's not working, please copy any error messages and the output of `ip a ls` here.

Comment: Found my problem, i forgot 1 letter of address*